# c:foreach with EL end value NumberFormatException

Tags: jsf, foreach, jstl, expression, el

I want to use a jstl foreach loop to to display a certain number of elements defined by an attribute of my managed bean:

```
 <c:forEach begin="0" end="#{MyBean.IntegerProperty}" step="1" var="o" >
   <h:commandButton value="#{MyBean.IntegerProperty}"></h:commandButton>
 </c:forEach>
```

my taglib declaration is:

```
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

however i get this exception:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "#{MyBean.IntegerProperty}"
...
```

i've read somewhere that foreach and EL do not cooperate too well with each other, if so then does someone know a workaround solution to put that int value in the end attribute of c:foreach?

thank you in advance!

Comment: which jstl/el version are you using? in early versions deferred expressions (the ones with `#{}`) weren't allowed and it seems that's your case.

Comment: The `#{MyBean.IntegerProperty}` syntax can impossibly represent a valid property as it violates the Javabeans and EL specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't expect what you've got above to work because the JSTL tags don't form part of the Component tree.

For more, see [here](https://rogerkeays.com/jsf-c-foreach-vs-ui-repeat)

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly this would answer OP's concrete problem.

Comment: Apologies was intended as a comment